# I need a RegExp that's special

Tags: regex, notepad++, href

I need a custom RegExp. In a big text I want to remove any `href` tag with a certain URL. The perk is that those URLs are made by a server and contain an extra bit of url made of char-upper/lower-number.

So I would like Notepad++ to search and replace by naught all strings that contain an `a href+http://www.gymglish.com/workbook/show-lesson/+extrastring` like `xwSzAdM45jL6+</a>`
With http://www.gymglish.com/workbook/show-lesson/[a-zA-Z0-9/] Notepad++ find the string and perform the replacement till the first char of the extra bit (eg : xDghdS5jkA becomes DghdS5jkA).

I made a simple reasoning : if it does the replacement till the first char I must repeat the Regexp for 14 next chars thus 
http://www.gymglish.com/workbook/show-lesson/[a-zA-Z0-9\/][a-zA-Z0-9\/][a-zA-Z0-9\/][a-zA-Z0-9\/][a-zA-Z0-9\/][a-zA-Z0-9\/][a-zA-Z0-9\/][a-zA-Z0-9\/][a-zA-Z0-9\/][a-zA-Z0-9\/]/[a-zA-Z0-9\/][a-zA-Z0-9\/][a-zA-Z0-9\/][a-zA-Z0-9\/]>*</[a|A]> :-) however that's a dumb regexp

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it clear what the exact string is to be matched?

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/cB1hH2/1 `/(<a[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>)/g`

Comment: Every code is special. What makes you think yours is more special than anyone's else? Sounds kinda selfish.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick: (edited to use the new URL)

```
<[a|A] (href|HREF)=[\'|\"]http:\/\/www\.gymglish\.com\/workbook\/show-lesson[\/a-zA-Z0-9]*[\'|\"]>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*<\/[a|A]>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/zKYYq4L3ML74Rieb)

Comment: Why not just use the `i` flag and write it all in just one case?

Comment: ^Possible for Notepad++ ?

Comment: Ahh, gotcha! (Though they can just untick "Match Case", but hey `:)`)

Comment: Notepad++ does support inline modifiers like `(?i)`. Is there a reason for the `|` inside `[a|A]`? There is no reason to escape `'` or `"`.